# Spring boot gradle integration test with Spock

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, groovy, spock

I am using Spring Boot + Gradle + Spock (groovy) for integration and unit testing.
I was able to configure unit tests to work with Spock.
Integration tests fail to start because they do not see project files.
Here configuration I've done (cleaned up) for integrationtests.
I do believe issue is that I don't configured dependency properly + that integration tests in different directory.

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        groovy.srcDir "$projectDir/src/integrationTest/groovy"
        resources.srcDir "$projectDir/src/integrationTest/resources"
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Directory structure is

```
src
 -main
      --java
 -test
      --groovy
 -integrationTest
      --groovy
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that you are on a new enough Gradle version, I recommend you use the JVM Test Suite Plugin to define your additional test suite. It is documented at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html and also shows your exact use-case, integration tests that need access to production code.